# Spring DispatcherServlet matches for wrong url-pattern

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat

I have following configuration in the Spring based project -

web.xml -

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Handler mapping from spring-servlet.xml -

```
    <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

and Spring Controller as -

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Now when I send request to

```
GET http://localhost:8080/test
```

I get response as `hello` which is fine but when I send request on following URL's -

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/test
GET http://localhost:8080/img/test
```

then also I get `hello` response i.e. controller code gets executed for above mentioned wrong URLs.

Is there anything wrong in the configuration or it's expected behaviour?

Comment: That is expected. All `/img` and `/api` are mapped to the dispatcher servlet, within that mapping it tries to find `/test` which in both cases will lead to your controller.

Comment: The result of `GET http://localhost:8080/test` is not really expected, since there is no servlet in your question bound to that path.

Comment: @M.Deinum, @Piotr P. Karwasz Sorry `servlet-mapping` entry for test was missing in question, now I updated the question with it. @M.Deinum but as the `test` endpoint is mapped at root i.e. `/test` it should not be executed under `/img/test` or `/api/test` right?

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What URL mapping are you trying to achieve? Why mapping the servlet to `/*` isn't enough?

Comment: No `/test` isn't mapped to root, it is mapped within the mapping of the `DispatcherServlet`. `/test` is the part **after** the URL mapping in the `DispatcherServlet`. You can change this to use the full path but by default it isn't.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz If I map `/*` all the URLs will be handled by Spring whereas I want Spring to handle only specific URLs.

Comment: Can you add your application context configuration to the question?

Comment: @M.Deinum Your comment "No `/test` isn't mapped to root, it is mapped within the mapping of the `DispatcherServlet`." makes sense. You mentioned, this configuration can be made to use full path but I could not find anything for this. Could you please share link which I can refer for this?

Comment: You can set that on the `HandlerMapping` instances that are in use.

Comment: Oh, then `alwaysUseFullPath` of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is already set to true.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping of an URL to a handler (a method) in Spring MVC is a two-step process:

- first the servlet container must decide whether to forward the request to the `DispatcherServlet` according to the `<servlet-mapping>`,
- then the `DispatcherServlet` consults its `HandlerMapping`s to see which one matches the request. A `HandlerMapping` can do anything, but usually calls [`UrlPathHelper#getLookupPathForRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper.html#getLookupPathForRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) to transform the request into a path.

The default behavior of the `UrlPathHelper` depends on the `<servlet-mapping>` used:

- if you used an exact mapping as in the case of `/test`, a request for `/test` will give  a path of `/test`,
- if you used a prefix mapping `/api/*`, a request for `/api/foo/bar` will result in a path of only `/foo/bar`.

As mentioned [in the comment by M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268266/spring-dispatcherservlet-matches-for-wrong-url-pattern#comment118947094_67268266) you need to set the `alwaysUseFullPath` property to true on the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` instance used by the `DispatcherServlet`.

In your XML application context configuration you define **a** bean of class `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, while you should overwrite **the** bean used by the `DispatcherServlet`. Therefore you need to use the same id internally used by Spring:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
   <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

**Remark:** This solution should work **unless** you invert the order of the definitions in your XML. In such a case the *default* definition will overwrite yours. Set the logger `org.springframework.beans.factory.support` do `DEBUG` to check which definition overwrites the other. In one case you get:

> Overriding **user-defined** bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping' with a **framework-generated** bean definition: ...

in the other:

> Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping' with a **different** definition: ...